# How to get rid of a 404 error code in more serverblocks in reverse nginx proxy

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, pm2

For my application I installed nginx 1.15.9 (as reverse proxy server) (on Ubuntu 18.04). I want to run an Angular app and a Node app (pm2) on this server and I get the angular app on my (sub)domain, but with a call from the angular app to the node app, I recieve a 404 error.

//path:  /etc/nginx/sites-available/zbs

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    //more Certbot stuff

  root /var/www/zbs/html/schoolsysteem-project/;

  location / {                //angular
          try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
  }

  location /api {             //pm2
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

//path:  /var/www/zbs/html/schoolsysteem-project

All the files of node and angular files I put in this directory.

//path: /var/www/zbs/html/schoolsysteem-project/routes/loginUser.js

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/loginUser', (req, res, next) => {
    //working code
  });
}
```

//path:  /var/www/zbs/html/schoolsysteem-project/index.js

```
require('babel-register')({
   presets: [ 'es2015' ]
});

require('./server');
```

//path:  /var/www/zbs/html/schoolsysteem-project/server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import Cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';
import passport from 'passport';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const API_PORT = process.env.API_PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('./config/passport');

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(passport.initialize());

//Cross Origin Resource Sharing
var corsWhitelist = [
    'http://localhost:4200',
  'http://localhost:4200/*'
];

var corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback){
        var isWhitelisted = corsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, isWhitelisted);
    },
    credentials:true
}

app.use(Cors(corsOptions));

//routes
require('./routes/getDownloadPdfWithPost')(app);
require('./routes/loginUser')(app);
require('./routes/registerUser')(app);
require('./routes/forgotPassword')(app);
require('./routes/resetPassword')(app);
require('./routes/updatePassword')(app);
require('./routes/updatePasswordViaEmail')(app);
require('./routes/findUser')(app);
require('./routes/getSubjectWithPost')(app);
require('./routes/deleteUser')(app);
require('./routes/updateUser')(app);
require('./routes/addSubject')(app);
require('./routes/updateUserSubjectEnrollment')(app);
require('./routes/updateSubjectTab')(app);
require('./routes/api/test')(app);

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT}`));

module.exports = app;
```

And the call from the angular app:

```
this._http.post<any>(`https://mijn.<some domain>.nl/api/loginUser`, JSON.parse(userJsonArr)).subscribe((val) => { 
//more code
)}
```

How can I call the pm2 (node) routes and get this working?

I want to separate the node code and the angular code as well. How can I do that, with two roots or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: hi Richard,
This block [ / ] is already working. The [ /api ] block gives a 404 error.